# debugging web page issue

Tags: html, netbeans

I am trying to build several web sites that will share a common library folder. I am trying to put the library folder one level above the folder that has the index.html file and reference it as follows: ../mylibfolder/lib.js . I no issue with this when I run the page from a server. 
When I try this with an IDe program like jetbrains or netbeans that uses a local server for debugging it cannot find the files of the library. With netbeans I have the source folder and the library folder in the project and I get the following error:
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE "
In chrome I used the developer tools to check what sources are there and both folder are showing up under the local server.
Am I missing a setting in the program or in chrome to get the debugging to work with this file structure? 
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: If "../mylibfolder/lib.js" is relative to the website root, the browser won't be able to load that resource since it's not in the public folder.

Comment: Thanks. So does this mean it should not work when it is on server either ??

Comment: I don't know exactly how you have all the files structured so it's hard to say. If your domain is "example.com" and when you visit it, it loads "index.html", it won't be able to load "../script.js" because it's outside of the document root. If the web browser can load that file, your web server has a security flaw.